# Проблема с перегрузкой операторов

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Есть родительский класс с перегрузкой оператора +

```
    class Figure {
public:
    static sf::RenderWindow *windluz;

    static int N;

    static const int MAX;

    sf::Vector2f position, size;
    sf::Color color;

    virtual double square() {};

    virtual void draw() {};

    virtual void move(sf::Vector2f shift) {};

    virtual void scale(double zoom) {};

    Figure(sf::Vector2f position, sf::Vector2f size, sf::Color color);
    friend Figure * operator+(Figure *a, Figure b) {
        a = &b;
        Figure::N++;
        return a;
    }
};
```

Дочерний класс

```
class Rectangle : public Figure {
public:
    sf::RectangleShape rectangleShape;

    Rectangle(sf::Vector2f position, sf::Vector2f size, sf::Color color);

    void draw();


    void move(sf::Vector2f shift);

    void scale(double zoom);

    double square();

    double square(double a, double b);
};
```

В файле main

```
sf::RenderWindow *Figure::windluz;

int Figure::N = 0;

const int Figure::MAX = 10;

Figure *array[Figure::MAX];
```

и в функции main

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1920, 1080), "classes");

Figure::windluz = &window;


Rectangle rectangle(sf::Vector2f(60, 120), sf::Vector2f(60, 80), sf::Color::Black);

array[Figure::N] + rectangle;
```

при попытке вызвать метод из элемента массива происходит ошибка segmentation fault

```
for (int i = 0; i < Figure::N; ++i) {
     array[i]->draw(); //segmentation fault
}
```

подозреваю что проблема в неправильной перегрузке оператора, потому что если записать элемент в массив напрямую то все в порядке

```
array[Figure::N] = &rectangle;//работает
```

мне нужно записать элемент в массив именно с помощью "+"

Comment: Ничего не понял. Так где какая-либо осмысленная инициализация элементов массива `array`? В `array` изначально сидят null-указатели. `array[Figure::N] + rectangle` на значение элемента массива никак не влияет, то есть там так и остаются null-указатели. Ясно, что при вызове все упадет. Как это должно было работать?

Comment: И что такое "записать элемент в массив именно с помощью +"?

Comment: @AnT в массив с помощью оператора + вот так "array[Figure::N] + rectangle;" должна добавляться ссылка на новый элемент, что бы потом можно было пройтись по массиву и у любого дочерного класса вызвать метод отрисовки.

Comment: @AnT я не понимаю как инициализировать этот массив.

Answer (score 0):

Что у вас с классами? Посмотрите на них: у вас используются указатели в классах, но при этом не видно ни деструкторов ни конструкторов копирования. Тобишь при уничтожение объекта память не будет освобождаться, а при копировании указатель просто задвоится, а не будет скопирована полезная информация.

Следующее: что это вообще за код?

```
friend Figure * operator+(Figure *a, Figure b) {
    a = &b;
    Figure::N++;
    return a;
}
```

Вы передаете в функцию `Figure b` по значению (тоесть копируете объект - а конструктора копирования у вас нет!), а потом берете его адрес, присваиваете указателю `a` и возвращаете его... Что это за порнография? Для того, чтобы так делать, вы должны были передать `b` не по значению, а по адресу.

Дальше: что означает

```
Figure *array[Figure::MAX];
```

Вы вкурсе, что вы создали массив указателей? Тоесть в каждом элементе `array` стоит не объект, а указатель на него. Происходит ли инициализация? Думаю, что вы об этом не позаботились. Но окей, давайте сделаем так:

```
Figure array[Figure::MAX];
```

Тогда элементы будут объектами, а не указателями на них. Но вот только вы не позаботились о конструкторе по умолчанию. Да и вообще что это за классы у вас такие? Почему методы вместе с переменными в `public`? Классы не для этого были созданы, чтобы вот так с ними обращаться. Данные нужно скрывать и давать доступ только через соответствующие методы. Об инициализации должны заботится конструкторы, а об освобождении памяти - деструкторы. То что вы делаете (не заботитесь о инициализации, сохранении и правильном использовании данных) как раз и приводит к таким ошибкам.

Comment: Мне нужен именно массив указателей в который с помощью перегрузки оператора + нужно добавить ссылку на объект

Comment: в этом случае присмотритесь к тому, что я писал про ваш вариант операции `+`.